# Deleting a directory starting with a specific string in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ubuntu, redhat

When I'm trying to delete all directories starting with tmp,
I used this command:

```
 find -type d -name tmp* -exec rmdir {} \;
```

And it does the trick, but this command is exiting with an error code:

```
find: `./tmp09098': No such file or directory
```

What causing failing my build.

Can anyone tell me how I can delete those folders without getting the error?

After trying what @anubhava suggested and quoted 'temp*',

```
find -type d -name 'tmp*' -exec rmdir {} \;
```

I still get the same error:

```
find: `./tmp0909565g': No such file or directory

find: `./tmp09095': No such file or directory
```

When running:

```
find -type d -name 'tmp*' -exec ls -ld '{}' \;
```

This is the result:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun 16 10:08 ./tmp0909565g
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun 16 10:07 ./tmp09095
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun 16 10:08 ./tmp09094544656
```

Comment: And you're running `find` command as `root` user?

Comment: Yes, I'm connected as root

Comment: The directory was deleted without any warnings\messages

Comment: same issue - different warning+++> find: cannot delete `/tmp/tmp': Directory not empty

Comment: find: paths must precede expression: rm
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]

Comment: it also delets the /tmp folder i'm in,
so I get another warning : find: `/tmp/tmp': No such file or directory

Comment: find: `/tmp/tmp/tmp90978': No such file or directory

Comment: By the way I don't mind putting exit 0 at the end as long as I know it actually deletes the files\folders

Comment: in /tmp/tmp , but it shouldn't matter

Comment: This should work: `find . -type d -name 'tmp*' -mindepth 1 -exec rm -rf '{}' \; -prune`

Comment: That's right! Tnx man

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should quote the pattern otherwise it will be expanded by shell on command line:

```
find . -type d -name 'tmp*' -mindepth 1 -exec rm -rf '{}' \; -prune
```

`-prune` causes `find` to not descend into the current file/dir.

Comment: I tried to quote but I'm still getting this error message

Comment: It looks like he first delete it and only than trying to find it, but the directory isn't there because it was deleted

Comment: Can you paste output of  `find -type d -name 'tmp*' -exec ls -ld '{}' \;` in question

Comment: I pasted ^ in the question

Comment: I pasted the ls -ld   in the question ^

Comment: Thanks @anubhava, Worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
    #! /bin/bash

    tmpdirs=`find . -type d -name "tmp*"`

    echo "$tmpdirs" |

    while read dir;
    do
     echo "Removing directory $dir"
     rm -r $dir;
    done;
```

Comment: it doesn't fail my build , but it doesn't delete anything

Comment: To clarify: it never deleted anything in the first place, or it stopped deleting things properly when you added `2> /dev/null` ?

Comment: it stopped deleting things properly when you added 2> /dev/null

Comment: Thanks,
But I ended up using @anubhava answer